# Given a regular hexagon, prove a vector identity regarding its sides

Tags: geometry, vectors, plane-geometry

I'm given an exercise:

Given a regular hexagon whose vertices are $A, B, C, D, E, F$, and where $A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1, E_1, F_1$ are midpoints of $ \overline{AB}$, $ \overline{BC}$, $ \overline{CD}$, $ \overline{DE}$, $ \overline{EF}$, $ \overline{FA}$ respectively, prove that:

$\vec{AA_1} + \vec{BB_1} + \vec{CC_1} + \vec{DD_1} + \vec{AA_1} +\vec{EE_1} + \vec{FF_1} = \vec{0} $

Before I ask anything else, I want to point out that I'm not 100% sure that there should be a second $\vec{AA_1}$ in the equation, so it might be a typo. However, I tried doing the exercise in both cases and simply failed to do it. Could anyone help?

Comment: 1. The extra summand _is_ a typo. (Hint: Argue by symmetry.) 2. Can you see geometrically why the sum (arrow accents omitted) $AB + BC + \cdots + FA = 0$? 3. Can you use 2. to finish? (Hint: How is $AA_1$ related to $AB$, and similarly for the other terms under cyclic permutation of letters)?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, how much linear algebra do you know?

Comment: Hint: $\overrightarrow {AB}=-\overrightarrow {DE}$, thus $\overrightarrow {AA_1}=-\overrightarrow {DD_1}$